# keeping checked checkbox state unless unchecked

Tags: php, jquery, html

I had asked this question but did not get a solution. By short explanation I would like the checked checkboxes to stay checked unless unchecked by the user: on page refresh.

I am able to keep the boxes checked on page refresh but when the page id changes(I have pagination) like `index.php?page=2` the boxes get unchecked so is there a way that I can get the boxes to stay checked unless unchecked even if the page id changes?

I am displaying results from database and the user can filter results. If the user clicks on the next page for more results I would like to keep the checked boxes stay checked so that I can show filtered results from page 2. I really need help. Thanks

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
            <input type="checkbox" name="sa" class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_POST['sa'])?' checked':'')?>/>Samsung<br>
 </form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.checkbox').on('change',function(){
        $('#form').submit();
     });
});



</script>
```

I have tried this jquery function along with the above one but it doesn't work.

```
$("input.checkbox").each(function() {
    var mycookie = $.cookie($(this).attr('name'));
    if (mycookie && mycookie == "true") {
        $(this).prop('checked', mycookie);
    }
});
$("input.checkbox").change(function() {
    $.cookie($(this).attr("name"), $(this).prop('checked'), {
        path: '/',
        expires: 365
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to save the states of the checkboxes into cookie(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sa" class="checkbox" value="yes"
      <?php echo ($_POST['sa'] == 'yes')? ' checked="checked"':'' ?>/>Samsung<br>
```

The proper mark-up being

```
checked="checked"
```

to get that to stay active based on your condition.

This only occurs if you are continuing through other pages **WITH the form being used** to get to them.  If you only expect people to use the form once, you should set a SESSION or GET variable to carry that value through other pages without the use of the form.

So, for example, keep the form almost the same, except change your condition and include this in your header, before you spit out the form -

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['changeit']))  {
    if( $_POST['sa'] == 'yes') {
        $_SESSION['checked'] = true; 
    } else {
        $_SESSION['checked'] = false; 
    }
}
?>
```

then make you're condition for spitting out checked:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sa" class="checkbox" value="yes"
  <?php echo ($_SESSION['checked'] == true)? ' checked="checked"':'' ?>/>Samsung<br>
```

and include a hidden input to only check if the checkbox has changed.

```
<input type="hidden" name="changeit" />
```

that way, the condition for setting the session is only checked if the form checkbox was checked or unchecked... so your whole structure should look something like this -

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['changeit']))  {
    if( $_POST['sa'] == 'yes') {
        $_SESSION['checked'] = true; 
    } else {
    $_SESSION['checked'] = false; 
    }
}
?>
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
   <input type="checkbox" name="sa" class="checkbox" value="yes"
      <?php echo ($_SESSION['checked'] == true)? ' checked="checked"':'' ?>/>Samsung<br>
    <input type="hidden" name="changeit" />  
 </form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.checkbox').on('change',function(){
        $('#form').submit();
     });
});
</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The fundamental note is that POST variables will not transfer over from page to page if the form isn't being used.  The "action" is not called, thus the post is not sent.  You have to use either COOKIES or SESSIONS or GET variables to have this cross over pages without the use of the form every time.

Comment: it will keep it checked based on the `$_POST['sa']` condition.  I would include the `value` attribute and use that as your condition.

Comment: it gives me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';' `

Comment: try now.  my shorthand conditionals are a bit rusty

Comment: now it gives me `Notice: Undefined index: sa in` would you try to include `isset`? If checkbox only checked.

Comment: No luck. I gave up. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I know why... its more about how the variables are being sent and stored.  POST variables are only stored through a form, one time, and are not saved.  You need a method that stores them across multiple pages.

Comment: oh yeah this works perfect. Thanks very much. Btw if the user checks and uncheks can I do some else statements? As I stated I am displaying results from database and if the user checks the filtered rows will be returned if unchecks then all the row. Many thanks

Comment: sure.  whatever query you want to perform on the DB, have it altered based on the SESSION now.  So `if($_SESSION['checked'] == true) { query the DB with filters } else { query the DB and select all }` sort of thing.  hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

RCNeil's answer is correct, in that if the post key 'sa' is set, the checkbox will be checked="checked".

To expand on his answer, It doesn't have to be from a post value, it can be pulled from the database, or anywhere really.  It just needs to return a boolean (True/False). The following would also work:

```
//Some logic
$YourVariable = true; //for example
//Then the checkbox conditional
<input type="checkbox" name="sa" class="checkbox"
      <?=($YourVariable)?' checked="checked"':'')?>/>Samsung<br>
```

Will return as the checked="checked" and the checkbox marked by default. (Unless, bool false)

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sa" class="checkbox" checked="checked" value="forever"
      <?=(isset($_POST['sa'])?:'')?>/>Samsung<br>
```

I guess this should work

Comment: The user first have to check the boxes, it shouldn't be checked automatically.

Comment: My bad guys, misunderstood it