# How can I retain checkbox value after page refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to retain the value of multiple checkbox after the page is refreshed. Based on my research, I found two viable options 1) using session variables or 2) via localStorage. I decided to choose localStorage since it is optimized for modern browsers. I wrote the code based on this example: [Keep checkbox checked even after page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449677/keep-checkbox-checked-even-after-page-refresh) .
When I toggle the switch on/off it works normally. But, if I toggle it on and refresh the page (going in the address bar and press enter), it get unchecked and the value in the database is set to 0 (from 1).

I don't what is wrong with the code. Can someone please advise me?

Thanks

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$database ="xxxxx";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//echo "Connected successfully";
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
 <head>  
      <meta charset="utf-8">  
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>  
 <body>  

<?php
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST) >= 0){
    
    if (isset($_POST['checkbox1'])) {

        $query1 = "UPDATE switch_status SET status = 1 WHERE switch_id = 1";
    } else {
        $query1 = "UPDATE switch_status SET status = 0 WHERE switch_id = 1";
    }
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1) or die(mysqli_error());
}
     
?>


<form id="form" action="" method="POST" >

        <label>
            Checkbox 1
            <input type="checkbox"  id = "check" name="checkbox1" value="1" autocomplete="off" onchange="document.getElementById('form').submit();"
                <?php if(isset($_POST['checkbox1'])) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>>
        </label>



    </form>
<script>
$('#check').on('click', function(){

  if(localStorage.getItem("checkedbox") == 'true') {
    $(this).prop(checked, 'false');
    localStorage.setItem("checkedbox", 'false');

  }
  else {
    $(this).prop(checked, 'true');
     localStorage.setItem("checkedbox", 'true');
  }

})
</script>
 </body>  
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering, I solved my issue by using session variables instead of the localStorage data. This was done by following these threads: [Store a checked checkbox from a form in a session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46296980/store-a-checked-checkbox-from-a-form-in-a-session) and [keeping checked checkbox state unless unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175132/keeping-checked-checkbox-state-unless-unchecked).

Thank you to everyone that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than set the checked property from a PHP post variable (which won't be there if you just refresh the page without submitting), utilize the localStorage data. You can also simplify your function a bit

```
<form id="form" action="" method="POST">
  <label>Checkbox 1 <input type="checkbox"  id = "check" name="checkbox1" value="1" autocomplete="off" /> </label>
</form>

<script>
  // start by retrieving the current state
  $(document).ready(function() {
    let isChecked = localStorage.getItem("checkedbox");
    // now set it
    $('#check').prop('checked', isChecked)
  });

  $('#check').on('click', function() {
    localStorage.setItem("checkedbox", $(this).prop('checked'));
    // if you really want to submit the form when someone checks it...
    $('form').submit();
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `$_POST` superglobal is always defined so your check `if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST) >= 0){` will always be true.
Also when you have an unchecked checkbox it is not posted so your `$_POST` will be empty for valid requests. Pressing enter in the address bar makes a GET request, but your code can't tell the difference between a GET and POST request, so instead of checking if $_POST is set check the request method.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['checkbox1'])) {

        $query1 = "UPDATE switch_status SET status = 1 WHERE switch_id = 1";
    } else {
        $query1 = "UPDATE switch_status SET status = 0 WHERE switch_id = 1";
    }
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Web pages have no memory.  When you "submit" data from a form and go to, say, the same web page again, the only stuff you have is what is in $_REQUEST, $_POST, and/or $_GET.

You *can* save stuff in $_SESSION, but that is probably not what you are asking about.  Caution:  That *only* works if you have only a single web server.  Large web sites use multiple servers interchangeably; "sessions" don't work in that context; a database is needed.

Instead, you need to look at what is in $_GET (etc) and use that to construct the value that you need.  In the case of a "checkbox", you have to actually modify the `<input>` to include the keyword "checked".  Similarly for "options" and "text".  For "text" you fill in the "value=" *after suitably escaping the text* (using `htmlentities()`).

As for "local storage" vs "session" vs "database" -- the performance difference is not significant.  If the value is in $_POST (etc), then that is the least effort.

You can simply use $_REQUEST to avoid knowing whether it was `<form method=POST>` or `<form method=GET>`.